# Need to log the error details when powershell goes down accidentally

Tags: powershell

We are having a scheduler which is developed in powershell 1.0. It will be running in infinite loop as a service in our server. Some times powershell is going down automatically.

We need to log some useful information to troubleshoot this issue. 
Can someone please help us on this?

Thanks,

Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `trap` instruction at the very begining of your script. The `trap` instruction will catch any exception in your PowerShell code. In the trap scriptblock you just have to log the exception, in a file or in windows logs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. While investigating this issue we have identified whenever someone is connecting the remote machine with Admin privilege and logging off directly instead of closing the remote window, Powershell is going down automatically. We need to know who is currently logged on with admin privilege and logged of the remote session. This information should be logged somewhere. Can you please help on finding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can record a full transcript of the PowerShell session by adding this to the beginning of the script:

```
Start-Transcript <path to transcript file> -Append
```

For convenience, give the transcript file a .txt extension.

The **-Append** switch will keep each session from overwriting transcripts from earlier sessions. You will be able to tell what output is from which session because the transcript adds a header and footer telling you what time the transcript started and ended, as well as the hostname, OS version, and what account it ran under.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, it's obviously not possible for the PowerShell session itself to report when it terminates unexpectedly, but you can have another script start it as a background job and keep polling it until it ends, then report the time and exit status. This function will do the trick:

```
function Measure-EndTime {
  param(
    [string]$Command,
    [int]$PollingInterval  # seconds
  )

  $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$Command}
  do {
    sleep $PollingInterval
  } until ($job.State -ne 'Running')
  echo "Job ended $(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff'): $($job.State)"
}
```

You'd invoke it like this:

```
Measure-EndTime -Command "& <path>\scheduler.ps1" -PollingInterval 10
```

That'll give you the end time with ~10 second accuracy, with a message like `Job ended 2013-08-05_17-57-18.24: Completed`. You can increase or decrease the polling interval for the degree of accuracy you want weighed against the system load you want to bear. The polling interval doesn't have to be an integer. You can set it to **.25** to poll every quarter second if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. Please find the output which we have recieved below in text file.
We could see the start time. However we are not able to see the end time for this. 
Is there anything else we needs to add in the command line which you provided for displaying the end time.

Comment: Here is the output:  **********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
Start time: 20130731110940
Username : Test\Test_services
Machine : Test (Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2)
**********************
Transcript started, output file is Test.txt
COMPONENT SCHEDULER POWERSHELL SCRIPT VERSION 1.1
Removing .pgp extension from all files including (.IN, .txt and .cps)
Next execution: 2013-07-31 11:10:18
***********************

Comment: The end time is displayed automatically, but only if PowerShell exists cleanly or the transcript is manually stopped with **Stop-Transcript**. If the powershell process is still running, or the scheduler kills it, there won't be an end time.

Comment: Thanks Adi. We have tried proper exit and we could see end time in the text file. however we are looking for the end time, when someone kills the session or system terminates the session abnormally. Can you please suggest on this scenario?

Comment: Well, the PowerShell session itself obviously can't report when it's terminated unexpectedly, but you could have a script run it as a background job and keep polling the job until it ends, then report the time and the exit status.

Comment: I added a function to the answer that launches and monitors a command or script and reports when it ended. Since the monitoring function is independent of the process it launches, it can report when the process stopped running even if the process is abruptly killed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to subscribe to the PowerShell.Exiting engine event. It will not work if PowerShell was closed not via the X button and I don't know for sure that it works if PowerShell has crashed unexpectedly.

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent –Action { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks shay. we have tried the below command.

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action {"PowerShell exited at " + (Get-Date) | Out-File d:\ag\log.txt -Append}

We could successfully see the last exit time of powershell session. But it is not working whenever the session gets terminated abnormally or we are closing it manually.
Can you please suggest on this?